# How do I multiply two integers where one is larger than 32 bits in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the following subroutine that is used to find $a0 to the power of $a1. It works fine for small integers, but I want it to work for something like 1000^6. I was thinking that if I store the hi register for the multiplication in $v1.

So I guess my main question is, "How do I multiply two integers where one is larger than 32 bits?"

```
pow:
  li    $v0, 1
pow_loop:
  ble   $a1, $zero, pow_conclude
  mult  $v0, $a0
  mflo  $v0
  addi  $a1, $a1, -1
  j     pow_loop
pow_conclude:
  jr    $ra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading Ben Jackson's answer, I wrote this and checked it with MARS.

```
pow:
  li    $v0, 1
  li    $v1, 0
pow_loop:
  ble   $a1, $zero, pow_conclude
  mult  $v1, $a0
  mflo  $v1
  mult  $v0, $a0
  mflo  $v0
  mfhi  $t0
  add   $v1, $v1, $t0
  addi  $a1, $a1, -1
  j     pow_loop
pow_conclude:
  jr    $ra
```

Comment: Cribbing some MIPS knowledge from your answer I updated mine.

Answer (score 1):

Remember how you multiplied numbers on paper in school.  Break your input down into 16- or 32-bit components and multiply all the partial products and add them together, minding the carry chain.

Without knowing MIPS, but based on @russjohnson09's self-answer:

Assuming you are doing 32*64 bits here (from `$a0` and `$v0,v1`) you will have a 96 bit result.  Something like this:

```
  mult  $v0, $a0
  mflo  $v0
  mfhi  $v2
  mult  $v1, $a0
  mflo  $v1
  add   $v1,$v1,$v2
```

The upper 32 bits of 96 are the carry of that `add` plus `mfhi` after the the second `mult`, but I am assuming you're in the loop and this upper part will always be 0.  In other words, continuous 32*64 truncated into 64 bits.