# How do multiply a 64bits with 32 bits in MIPS

Tags: mips

Im trying to multiply two  32bits in mips. So the result is stored in the high and low register. How can I multiply the 64bit to a 32 bit when the answer is stored in two registers?

Comment: What do you mean by _"multiply the 64bit to a 32 bit"_? Earlier in your question you talk about _"multiply two 32bits"_. Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: when u multiply two 32bits the answered is stored in 64bits...so my question is how can I mutliply a 64bit number that is stored in two regester with a 32 bit number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I multiply two integers where one is larger than 32 bits in MIPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587568/how-do-i-multiply-two-integers-where-one-is-larger-than-32-bits-in-mips)

Answer (score 2):

You multiply each half of the 64-bit value by the 32-bit value, then add the matching registers together, realizing you may need a third 32-bit register to represent the result.